# How to set select editor for a few cells in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm trying at add a table where in the first row I have a select editor.But all the examples are used for a whole column.How to set select editor for a few cells?

Answer (score 0):

```
cell: [
      {row: 1, col: 0, renderer: Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer}
    ],

cells: function (row, col, prop) {
      if (row === 0 && col === 0) {
        this.renderer = Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer;
      }
    }
```